How to prevent Android Chrome to implement download file name?
I wrote an app with R shiny to daily implement a calendar on android.
More practically, it uploads a file (containing a dataframe which represents the calendar), paste the "today" line to the existing dataframe and save the updated calendar.
The trick is to always keep the same file/name to keep track of data of every single day.
However, chrome does implement the name of my calendar when I download the new file (calendar(1).RData, calendar(2).RData...). On linux I can fix this by installing extensions but on android it seems more tricky.
I downloaded Chromium but I have to admit that I am lost what would be the solution.
Thanks in advance,
Charlotte
PS: one solution would be to delete the original data (How to delete a file created by a Shiny app when the ssession closes) but so dangerous, I would prefer just to switch a button on chrome extension :D
Here is my code (and my data : https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/0nh8858pfk7675phpl7hb/Horaires.RData?rlkey=4x924iexujalaojj3a8rzjg2s&dl=0):
library(shiny)
library(shinyTime)
library(shinyFiles)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Horaires Turbin :D"),
  
  fluidRow(
    div(
      fileInput("files", "File data", multiple=F),
      style="background-color:#ADD8E6;margin-right:2.5%;margin-left:2.5%;padding:2.5%;color:white;margin-bottom:2.5%"
      
    ),
    div(
      dateInput("date4", "Jour considéré", value = Sys.Date()),
      radioButtons("Situation", label = "Situation",
                   choices = c("Boulot", "Vacances", "Lab"), 
                   selected = "Boulot"),
      uiOutput("moreControls"),
      textInput("Note", "Note", ""),
      style="background-color:#ADD8E6;margin-right:2.5%;margin-left:2.5%;padding:2.5%;color:white;margin-bottom:2.5%"
      
    ),
    div(
      h2("A sauvegarder :"),
      uiOutput("toSave"),
      style="background-color:#ADD8E6;margin-right:2.5%;margin-left:2.5%;padding:2.5%;color:white;margin-bottom:2.5%",
    ),
    div(
      downloadButton("downloadData", "Save"),
      style="background-color:#ADD8E6;margin-right:2.5%;margin-left:2.5%;padding:2.5%;color:white;margin-bottom:2.5%"
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  

  calendrier <- reactiveValues(dat = NULL)
  dataToSave <- reactiveValues(dat = NULL)

  observe({
    
    output$moreControls <- renderUI({
      if(input$Situation == "Vacances"){
        NULL
      }else if(input$Situation == "Lab"){
        NULL
      } else if(input$Situation == "Boulot"){
        div(
          timeInput("time1", "Matin", value = strptime("00:00:00", "%T")),
          timeInput("time2", "Midi", value = strptime("00:00:00", "%T")),
          timeInput("time3", "Aprem", value = strptime("00:00:00", "%T")),
          timeInput("time4", "Soir", value = strptime("00:00:00", "%T"))
        )
      }
    })
    
    output$toSave <- renderUI({
      if(input$Situation == "Vacances"){
        div("Vacances", 
           p(input$Note))
      }else if(input$Situation == "Lab"){
        div("Lab", 
            p(input$Note))
      } else if(input$Situation == "Boulot"){
        div(
          paste0("Jour concerné : ", strftime(input$date4, "%d-%m-%Y")),
          br(),
          paste0("Matin : ", strftime(input$time1, "%T")),
          br(),
          paste0("Midi : ", strftime(input$time2, "%T")),
          br(),
          paste0("Aprem : ", strftime(input$time3, "%T")),
          br(),
          paste0("Soir : ", strftime(input$time4, "%T")),
          br(),
          input$Note
        )
      }
    })
  })
  
  observe({
    if(!is.null(input$files$datapath)){
      load(input$files$datapath)
      calendrier$dat <- ToSave
    } 
  })
  
  observe({

    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        "Horaires.RData"
      },
      content = function(file) {
        
        data <- c(as.character(input$date4),
                  as.character(strftime(input$time1, "%T")),
                  as.character(strftime(input$time2, "%T")),
                  as.character(strftime(input$time3, "%T")),
                  as.character(strftime(input$time4, "%T")),
                  as.character(input$Note))
        
        ToSave <- rbind(calendrier$dat, data)
        save(ToSave, file = file)
      }
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


I'm a little confused here. The "how to delete a file" link you provide deletes a stale file on the server and has nothing to do with deleting files on the client machine, and asking that the server be allowed to delete files on the client machine would be a gaping security risk. The server has no influence over how the client chooses to deal with duplicate named download files, or even awareness that it occurs. Due to all of that, I think your issue has nothing to do with [tag:r] or [tag:shiny] and everything to do with download-management on [tag:android].

I understand your confusion. My idea when I wrote that PS was to address my question to R/Shiny users that may see another way/logic to my problem, so we could go in R code direction. But yes my main goal is to overwrite a file on android chrome. Should I edit my post ? or is it helpful for other to undrestand the logic ?

Thank you for the clarification. It's typically better to have full clarity in the question, over to you if you want to edit it. Regardless, I don't think there's a way you can you simple HTTP/shiny on android to control how the local browser deals with same-name downloads. It seems that your issue is how to keep data "stored" in a web app so that the user can revisit your shiny page, optionally upload a file, then get it updated, is that correct? You might consider HTTP Local Storage, perhaps shinyStorePlus.
